# Set CurrentPosition of MultiSelectCollectionView after Refresh

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

Is there a workaround to set the CurrentPosition of a MultiSelectCollectionView after Refresh is called?

I declare the following:

```
MultiSelectCollectionView<customersViewModel> Customers { get; set; }
```

I then do a Refresh after a bulk update :

```
Customers.Refresh();
```

This is fine but I lose the current cursor position - it goes back to position 1, after Refresh() is called.

Ideally, I'd like to call something like :

```
Customers.CurrentPosition = _currentPosition;
```

after the Refresh, but it's a read-only property.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what MultiSelectCollectionView is, but assuming it implements ICollectionView you have some methods available for navigating the currently selected position in the view.

It seems like you could use the MoveCurrentToPosition method to reselect the item that was selected before the refresh.

```
var _currentPosition = Customers.CurrentPosition;
Customers.Refresh();
Customers.MoveCurrentToPosition(_currentPosition);
```